# Google Charts - Display two or more donuts rings in one donut chart

Tags: javascript, css, html, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts. I have the below code.

```
var newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Major', 'Degrees'],
  ['Business', 2], ['Education', 2],
  ['Social Sciences & History', 2], ['Health', 2],
  ['Psychology', 2]]);
var newData2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Major', 'Degrees'],
  ['Business', 2], ['Education', 3],
  ['Social Sciences & History', 1], ['Health', 2],
  ['Psychology', 4]]);
var options = { pieSliceText: 'none'};
var chartDiff = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
var diffData2 = chartDiff.computeDiff(newData, newData2);
chartDiff.draw(diffData2, options);
```

I am getting the following output.

http://tinypic.com/r/1ggizc/8

I would like to get the do-nut chart like the below image.

http://tinypic.com/r/169rbpz/8

Is there any other way to get the donut charts as shown in the second link above. I would like it only in Google charts please. Suggestion in code modification or complete code change is also fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly google API doesnt have a option to provided many donuts in a songle google donut chart :)